# tar on windows fails to extract symlink out of archive

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, tar, cmake

While trying to install GTK with vcpkg it fails to extract [libexpat-libexpat-R_2_2_6.tar.gz](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/archive/R_2_2_6.tar.gz):

```
Building package expat[core]:x64-windows...
-- Downloading https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/archive/R_2_2_6.tar.gz...
-- Extracting source C:/Users/USER/git/vcpkg/downloads/libexpat-libexpat-R_2_2_6.tar.gz
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:56 (message):
    Command failed: C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe;-E;tar;xjf;C:/Users/USER/git/vcpkg/downloads/libexpat-libexpat-R_2_2_6.tar.gz
    Working Directory: C:/Users/USER/git/vcpkg/buildtrees/expat/src/TEMP
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\USER\git\vcpkg\buildtrees\expat\extract-err.log
```

extract-err.log:

```
CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_header(): Can't create ''
CMake Error: Current file: libexpat-R_2_2_6/README.md
CMake Error: Problem extracting tar: C:/Users/USER/git/vcpkg/downloads/libexpat-libexpat-R_2_2_6.tar.gz
```

And running tar manually results in:

```
> tar xjf C:/Users/USER/git/vcpkg/downloads/libexpat-libexpat-R_2_2_6.tar.gz
libexpat-R_2_2_6/README.md: Can't create '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\USER\\git\\vcpkg\\buildtrees\\expat\\src\\TEMP\\libexpat-R_2_2_6\\README.md'
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Versions:

- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437]
- cmake version 3.14.2
- bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.5.f-ipp
- vcpkg 2018.11.23-nohash (commit 0907798)

Edit:

The tar error is expected, the issue manifests in cmake where the expected output (see extract-err.log) should be:

```
cmake -E tar: warning: skipping symbolic link "libexpat-R_2_2_6/README.md" -> "expat/README.md".
```

Edit:

Looks like this is an active cmake issue https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19102

Comment: Have you tried running as Administrator?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexej Harm found the setting that causes this issue https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19102#note_558431.

The UTF-8 beta in intl.cpl > Administrative > Change system locale... needs to be unticked for cmake (3.14.2) to function properly.